# Regex - match '%20' in encoded tel URL

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, tel

I have the following regex:

```
 (?:[\s:]|\d+(?:-|.)|^)(?(\d{3}))?[- .]?(\d{3})[- .]?(\d{4})(?=<|\s|$)
```

**When copying the regex it looks that some escape backslashes got lost, so here is the correct regex:**
(?:[\s:]|\d+(?:-|\.)|^)\(?(\d{3})\)?[- \.]?(\d{3})[- \.]?(\d{4})(?=<|\s|$)

It is used in Tel Linker extension on Chrome to correctly format the telephone number links on a web page.

However, it fails to properly format a tel link when the empty spaces in the URL are encoded with '%20':
e.g.:

```
https://someresource.com/tel:(904)%20640-8301
https://someresource.com/tel:(904)%20640%208301
```

Unfortunately, I have no experience in working with Regex so any help/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Regex101 is complaining about the optional brackets. You likely need `\(?(\\d{3})\)?`

Comment: @vanowm Make sure to set Regex101 to ECMAScript. Only 1 error remains and it's just OP forgot a `:` after the third question mark.

Comment: Do you want to match an url where the `/tel:` part is mandatory?

Comment: From what I can tel from the Tel Linker overview, it detects the tel links and then tries to format the number using provided regex. I assume that it takes only the part after /tel:, and then applies the regex to identify the group of digits and then convert them to a clickable link that can be opened with a selected voice app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mplungjan pointed out, your regex is invalid.

Try this:

```
(?:[\s:]|\d+(?:-|.)|^)\(?(\d{3})\)?(?:%20)*(?:[- .]+(?:%20)*)?(\d{3})(?:(?:%20)*[- .]*(?:%20)*)?(\d{4})(?=<|\s|$)
```

If you use this as a string, you'll need escape every `\`:

```
(?:[\\s:]|\\d+(?:-|.)|^)\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?(?:%20)*(?:[- .]+(?:%20)*)?(\\d{3})(?:(?:%20)*[- .]*(?:%20)*)?(\\d{4})(?=<|\\s|$)
```

[Tested against](https://regex101.com/r/6iwxD9/2):

```
https://someresource.com/tel:(904)640-8301
https://someresource.com/tel:(904)%20640%208301
https://someresource.com/tel:(904)%20640-8301
https://someresource.com/tel:(904)%20640 - 8301
https://someresource.com/tel:(904)%20640%20-%208301
```

*Thanks @Casimir et Hippolyte for the suggestions*

Comment: Thank you for your help! The first suggestion is working! I tested it on regex101 and is generating the corect groups.

Comment: `(?:(?:%20)*|(?:%20)*[- .]*(?:%20)*)?` doesn't make sense: "an optional group where all the alternatives may be empty". It does exactly the same thing than `(?:%20)*[- .]*(?:%20)*` or better `(?:%20)*(?:[- .]+(?:%20)*)?`.  Same problem with `(?:(?:%20)?|(?:%20)*[- .]*(?:%20)*)?`. Instead of writing `(?=<|\s|$)`, use a negative lookahead with a negated character class: `(?![^<\s])` (=`not followed by a character that is **not** a "greater than" symbol nor a white-space` - note that this sentence allows the end of the string too).

Answer (score 1):

the regex you provided is invalid according to regex101

```
(?:[\s:]|\d+(?:-|.)|^)(?(\d{3}))?[- .]?(\d{3})[- .]?(\d{4})(?=<|\s|$)
```

without the ? in the capture group it is valid, and seems to match the right things:

```
(?:[\s:]|\d+(?:-|.)|^)((\d{3}))?[- .]?(\d{3})[- .]?(\d{4})(?=<|\s|$)
```

the `[- .]` is responsible for matching spaces in the tel, so replacing this with a regex that also matches `%20` would solve that: `(?:[- .]|%20)`:

```
(?:[\s:]|\d+(?:-|.)|^)((\d{3}))?(?:[- .]|%20)?(\d{3})(?:[- .]|%20)?(\d{4})(?=<|\s|$)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, indeed the regex was invalid. I tried the suggested solution and it does not match the first group of digits (i.e. 904 in the above examples).